# How to hide window of UIAgent process with cocoa

Tags: cocoa, macos, background-process, nsrunningapplication

I have an `UIAgent` application with one window. I want to hide/show it from another application.How do I do it with cocoa? Seems like `hide`/`unhide` methods of `NSRunningApplication` doesn't affect UIAgent processes.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it with `NSDistributionNotifications`. In the UIAgent application I add an observer to a `@"QuitProcessNotification"` (any other name):

```
[[NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
                             addObserver:self selector:@selector(quit:) 
                             name:@"QuitProcessNotification" 
                             object:@"com.MyCompany.MyApp" 
                             suspensionBehavior:NSNotificationSuspensionBehaviorDeliverImmediately];
```

The callback looks like that:

```
- (void) quit:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    [NSApp terminate:nil];
}
```

In the main application:
Sending notification:

```
[[NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
                     postNotificationName:@"QuitProcessNotification" 
                     object:@"com.MyCompany.MyApp"
                     userInfo: nil /* no dictionary */
                     deliverImmediately: YES];
```

Be sure, that the `object` parameter is indeed your sender application's bundle identifier.